# Connect Entity Framework with MYSQL in VS2019

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, entity-framework, visual-studio-2019, mysql-connector

I just installed Visual Studio 2019 and I´m trying to add a database with an ADO.NET entity model, but the wizard crashes in this step...

[Select Entity Framework Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCft4.png)

I have Visual Studio Community 2019 v16.4.5 
Installed MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.9  
Installed MySQL connector net 8.0.19

I added the references to my project 
MySQL.data 
MySQL.data.EntityFramework for EF6 
MySQL.web

all version 8.0.19, same as the connector

I also tried adding from nuget packages 
EntityFramework 
MySqlData 
MySql.Data.Entity 
MySql.Web

and added this to web.config

```
<entityFramework>
<providers>
<provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
</providers>
</entityFramework>
```

and tried everything I've read but it still doesnt work, it just crashes after that or it gives me this error

[Your Project references the latest version of Entity Framework](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZU5Uw.png)

Can someone please help? Am I adding worng versions?

Comment: Check your EntityFramework version, if it is EF5 look that https://stackoverflow.com/a/60927974/7731479

Comment: Thanks @[valeria](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60407053/12490425), it worked for me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, after many days I finally could add my data base.
I've seen comments of others saying the ADO wizard crashes so here's what I did...

With VS Community 2019
Installed latest versions of 
MySQL connector net
MySQL for Visual Studio

After created my project I went to admin NuGet packages and installed latest version of Entity Framework

Then in references added 
MySql.Data.EntityFramework for EF6

Then added this to my web.config

```
<entityFramework>
    <providers>
     <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.EntityFramework" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

Recompile
And the wizard works just fine!

It was very important to write MySql.Data.EntityFramework and not .EF6

Answer (score 0):

You can try pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.Mysql  provider

Answer (score 0):

In my case the <entity_framework> tags were there but malformatted and with an unversioned duplicate entry. Fixing that (FINALLY!!!) got a clean model generated.